# Ubuntu 22.04 - pinging from routers to other site in a site to site vpn (wireguard)

Tags: iptables, routing, linux-networking, wireguard

Here is my Setup...

I have two windows VM's are set at 192.168.51.100 and 192.168.52.100.
These two windows machines are able to ping each other and each router.  I am unable to ping from the routers to the remote network, say from 192.168.51.1 to 192.168.52.100 or .1

The persistent IP Tables (rules.v4 file) are as follows:
They are the same iptables on both routers.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

-A POSTROUTING -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT

# Completed on Tue Jul 12 00:56:20 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.4 on Tue Jul 12 00:56:20 2022
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:RH-Firewall-1-INPUT - [0:0]
:nat - [0:0]

-A INPUT -i ens160 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j RH-Firewall-1-INPUT
-A INPUT -i ens160 -m state --state INVALID,NEW -j DROP

-A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens192 -j nat
-A FORWARD -i ens160 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens160 -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ens160 -m state --state INVALID,NEW -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

#-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i enp0s3 -p udp -m udp --sport 67:68 --dport 67:68 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i wgo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i ens192 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p esp -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p ah -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
#-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
#-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 631 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
#-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

-A nat -i ens192 -j ACCEPT

COMMIT
```

Routing table of router1:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         _gateway        0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 ens160
192.168.51.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens192
192.168.52.0    192.168.51.1    255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 wg0
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens160
```

I did find out that I can ping the remote networks by forcing it to go out a specific IP.

`ping 192.168.52.100 -I 192.168.51.1`

But trying to use anything else doesn't work(wg0,ens192,ens160).  Is there a way to not have to specify the IP address?

Comment: usually you should have a gateway in the same network

Comment: The routers are the gateways.  As I mentioned the two windows VMs can talk to each other, just the routers can't talked to the opposite networks VM/router.